# JavaFX TableView Insert in ObservableList when column sorting is active

Tags: javafx

I have a JavaFX TableView defined as :

```
TableView<MyMessage> messages;
```

It is supported by an ObservableList :

```
private ObservableList<MyMessage> messagesList;

// Allocate the message list
messagesList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

// Set the list into place
messages.setItems( messagesList );
```

The **MyMessage** object has 10 fields all of type String.  There is a background operation that inserts **MyMessage** objects into the ObservableList.

```
messages.add( new MyMessage( String ... colData ) );
```

Everything works as advertised.  The table rows of the TableView are updated as objects are inserted into the ObservableList.

What doesn't seem to work as expected, is if I click on a column header to sort the table, the subsequent items inserted by the background thread are appended to the end of the table.  Not to the proper sorted row position.  If I click to resort the column, the table is resorted properly.

Do I need to some how force the re-sorting of the table each time I add something to the ObservableList? Or should the TableView take care of that for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Java FX 8 now has a [.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#sort--) method on tableView that can be called to re-trigger sorting.  Some operations will trigger a re-sort automatically but external events adding/deleting entries in the observable collection do not.

Answer (score 2):

> should the TableView take care of that for me

No.

There was a request that [TableView maintain sort order as the underlying list changes](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-19445) but it was closed as "not an issue".  You can review the comments on the issue for more detailed information.  In short, keeping the list sorted is the responsibility of the underlying ObservableList or the application maintaining the list.

> Do I need to some how force the re-sorting of the table each time I add something to the ObservableList?

In essence, yes.

JavaFX was supposed to ship with a SortedObservableList implementation which effectively cooperated with the TableView to make all of the sorting handling pretty much automatic for the application.  But, for JavaFX 2.2, the functionality did not make the cut for inclusion.  Currently, this functionality is scheduled for delivery as part of JDK/JRE8 and can be tracked via this [umbrella issue for improved sorting support in TableView](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-19479).

Comment: To force re-sorting, do we need to clear TableView.sortOrder() and reset it?